# Replacing a range of values in a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to rename values in a column such that values over a particular range are assigned a new name. As an example, I generated a random dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 10, TRUE), date = sample(1:20, 10, TRUE))
df
```

The data looks like this

```
   name date
1     g   19
2     m   11
3     e    3
4     i   20
5     m    4
6     q   12
7     x   17
8     s    1
9     z    4
10    x   19
```

Now I want to replace values using this code

```
df$date[df$date > 9 & df$date < 15 ]<- "L1"
df$date[df$date > 0 & df$date < 10 ]<- "L2"
df$date[df$date > 14 & df$date < 21 ]<- "L3"
df
```

I obtained the following result

```
   name date
1     g   L3
2     m   L1
3     e    3
4     i   L3
5     m    4
6     q   L1
7     x   L3
8     s   L2
9     z    4
10    x   L3
```

As you can see, some of the values were not changed. I was expecting this result

```
   name date
1     g   L3
2     m   L1
3     e   L2
4     i   L3
5     m   L2
6     q   L1
7     x   L3
8     s   L2
9     z   L2
10    x   L3
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date column gets coerced to a character vector after the first replacement.
To fix this simply add a new variable or work with one outside the data frame.

```r
# Method 1
set.seed(9871243)
df <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 10, TRUE), date = sample(1:20, 10, TRUE))

df$date2 <- df$date

df$date2[df$date > 9 & df$date < 15 ]<- "L1"
df$date2[df$date > 0 & df$date < 10 ]<- "L2"
df$date2[df$date > 14 & df$date < 21 ]<- "L3"
df
   name date date2
1     x    9    L2
2     o    9    L2
3     v    1    L2
4     h   15    L3
5     d   14    L1
6     d   19    L3
7     p   11    L1
8     j   13    L1
9     g   12    L1
10    i    6    L2

# Method 2
set.seed(9871243)
df <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 10, TRUE), date = sample(1:20, 10, TRUE))

date <- df$date

date[df$date > 9 & df$date < 15 ]<- "L1"
date[df$date > 0 & df$date < 10 ]<- "L2"
date[df$date > 14 & df$date < 21 ]<- "L3"

df$date <- date
df
   name date
1     x   L2
2     o   L2
3     v   L2
4     h   L3
5     d   L1
6     d   L3
7     p   L1
8     j   L1
9     g   L1
10    i   L2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints:**

1. With the first replacement `df$date[df$date > 9 & df$date < 15 ]<- "L1"` you are coercing date to a character vector.
   So you can add as.numeric() before df$date but you will keep having warnings like "NAs introduced by coercion"
2. Best way in my opinion is `ifelse`
3. one other option is to create new column date2 as proposed by @NicChr
4. Use `set.seed()` so that we can reproduce the same df

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 10, TRUE), date = sample(1:20, 10, TRUE))
df
#>    name date
#> 1     o   14
#> 2     s    5
#> 3     n   19
#> 4     c    9
#> 5     j    3
#> 6     r    8
#> 7     v    7
#> 8     k   10
#> 9     e    9
#> 10    t   19
df%>%
  mutate(date=ifelse(date>14 ,"L3",
                     ifelse(date>9,"L1",
                            ifelse(date>0,"L2",NA))))
#>    name date
#> 1     o   L1
#> 2     s   L2
#> 3     n   L3
#> 4     c   L2
#> 5     j   L2
#> 6     r   L2
#> 7     v   L2
#> 8     k   L1
#> 9     e   L2
#> 10    t   L3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>